"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" out of nowhere
I develop a 2d game in unity for hobby, but now, out of nowhere, this error message shows up and I do not know why this happens and where to fix it.

Anybody have an idea what this is and how to fix this?

From the error message I get that you are trying to access some properties or items of a List that was not initialized.

Yes, sounds like, but how do I find out what list it is?

See https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object.1394020/

Whuff, that was it, THANKS. Just a simple "reload"
